# Greatest Integer Function/Floor Function Definition? (Discrete Mathematics)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I came across this set builder definition for the greatest integer function (which is also equal to the floor function) in my Discrete Mathematics course indicated below:

${[[x]]} = {\lfloor{x}\rfloor}$

${\lfloor{x}\rfloor} = {\max{\left\{{{{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}
}\right\}}}$

My question is - is this equivalent to the following?:

${\max{\left\{{{{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}}\right\}}} \overset{?}= {\max{\left({{{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}}\right)}}$

More directly, is this equivalent to the following?:

${\lfloor{x}\rfloor} \overset{?}= {\max{\left({{{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}}\right)}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, the $\max$ is taken over a set, which is why braces are used in the definition given.

In many situations, where it's clear, the set description is omitted. For instance,

$$\max_{x\in[0,1]} f(x)$$

is used to mean $\max\{f(x)\,|\,x\in[0,1]\}$. Parentheses are not commonly used.

Comment: The maximum is not a function per se, it is an element of a set. Some sets have no such element.

Comment: "Technically, the max is taken over a set, which is why braces are used in the definition given." -Fimpellizieri

_

I always understood the max function as a function defined as: $\max()$; (with parenthesis); for example, for a function: f(x); the maximum can be found through: $\max{(f(x))}=[f'(0)]$ where $f'(0)$ is the derivative: $f'(x)$; evaluated at $0$.

Comment: This is a purely technical/notational distinction. Don't get too hung up on it.

Comment: "The maximum is not a function per se, it is an element of a set. Some sets have no such element." – Fimpellizieri _
I see what you mean as I googled "mathematics max function" and got the result from Wolfram: "The largest value of a set, function, etc."; where essentially the definition they list for $max()$ is as the maximum value of a set or a function, so in the case of ${\lfloor{x}\rfloor}$ the definition mentioned in the first post is the maximum value of the set of elements: $\left\{{{{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}
}\right\}$. (Source: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Maximum.html)

Comment: @ Fimpellizieri Thank you for the reply post as well as the comment posts. _
As a follow up, let me ask this, for the: ${{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}$; expression by itself is it correct to write: 
$\left({{{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}}\right)$ OR $\left\{{{{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}}\right\}$ ?

Comment: The standard accepted notation is that braces indicate a set. The parenthesized expression has no traditionally accepted meaning (even if it can be inferred from context).

Comment: "The standard accepted notation is that braces indicate a set. The parenthesized expression has no traditionally accepted meaning (even if it can be inferred from context)." – Fimpellizieri _ 
Understood. So, since the expression: ${{{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}}$; indicates a set the standard accepted notation would be the braces ($\{\}$) around it; as a result, that expression with the parenthesis ($()$) around it would not have a traditionally accepted meaning (even it can inferred from context), and consequently would not be correct to use. (1/2)

Comment: In summary, for the question ${\max{\left\{{{{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}}\right\}}} \overset{?}= {\max{\left({{{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}}\right)}}$ the expression: $\left({{{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}}\right)$; itself would not be correct to use and consequently cannot be said to equal to the correct expression: $\left\{{{{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}}\right\}$. In summary: ${\max{\left\{{{{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}}\right\}}} \neq {\max{\left({{{m}\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\mid{{m}\leq{x}}}\right)}}$. I have marked your reply as the answer. :) (2/2)